# Aggregate rows inside new columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, aggregate-functions

I would like to join the two first tables (Product and ProductProperties) to get the result in the bottom.

[image: 1]

How do I do this?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I couldn't get all the information on one line without having null values in some colons

Comment: Show us the SQL you used.

Answer (score 2):

There are penalties for EAV.  I'm not saying EAV is evil, but should be deployed carefully and with great forethought.

Here are two examples.  The first is a `PIVOT`, and the second is a `conditional aggregation`.

I tend to lean towards the `conditional aggregation`, it offers more flexibility and often a performance bump

Untested for you did not supply sample data and desired results as text

```
Select *
 From  (
         Select A.product_id
               ,A.product_name
               ,B.product_property
               ,B.product_property_value
          From  Product A
          Join ProductProperties B on A.product_id=B.product_di
       ) src
 Pivot (max( product_property_value ) for product_property in ([Price],[Category],[Status] ) ) pvt
```

---

```
Select A.product_id
      ,A.product_name
      ,Price    = max( case when product_propery='Price'    then product_propery_value end)
      ,Category = max( case when product_propery='Category' then product_propery_value end)
      ,Status   = max( case when product_propery='Status'   then product_propery_value end)
 From  Product A
 Join  ProductProperties B on A.product_id=B.product_di
 Group By A.product_id,A.product_name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
b.product_id
,b.product_name
,Price = MAX(IIF(p.product_property = 'Price',p.product_property_value,NULL))
,Category = MAX(IIF(p.product_property = 'Category',p.product_property_value,NULL))
,Status = MAX(IIF(p.product_property = 'Status',p.product_property_value,NULL))
FROM books b (nolock)
JOIN prodprop p (nolock)
ON b.product_id = p.product_id
GROUP BY b.product_id,b.product_name
```